# VueJS get unique values from array of objects based on key in watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have a watch to check the selected tags:

```
watch: {
  search (val) {
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      this.form_data.products_credit.push({
        product_id: val[i].id,
        quantity: null,
        package_size: null,
        purchase_price: null,
        warehouse_id: null
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine but the problem when the user select for example **tag1** then 
`this.form_data.products_credit` value is equal to:

```
[
  {
    product_id: 1,
    quantity: null,
    package_size: null,
    purchase_price: null,
    warehouse_id: null
  }
]
```

After that if the user selected **tag2** then `this.form_data.products_credit` result will be:

```
[
      {
        product_id: 1,
        quantity: null,
        package_size: null,
        purchase_price: null,
        warehouse_id: null
      },
      {
        product_id: 2,
        quantity: null,
        package_size: null,
        purchase_price: null,
        warehouse_id: null
      },
      {
        product_id: 2,
        quantity: null,
        package_size: null,
        purchase_price: null,
        warehouse_id: null
      }
    ]
```

> What I am expecting:

I was not expecting the duplicated that happened after selecting another tag but that is normal since I am looping throw them.

> What I have done:

I have tried to empty my `products_credit` before the loop like this:

`this.form_data.products_credit = []`

before the loop.

It worked fine but I don't want it that way because it will has side-effects on my next step.

A working example of the problem: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bLofrxye/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your array does not already contains your product before adding it :

```
watch: {
  search (val) {
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      if (
        !this.form_data.products_credit.some(item => {
          item.product_id === val[i].id
        })
      ) {
        this.form_data.products_credit.push({
          product_id: val[i].id,
          quantity: null,
          package_size: null,
          purchase_price: null,
          warehouse_id: null
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I feel like there are much simpler and quicker solutions to your problem with computed properties based on an array of tags generated by a user's input . If you are able to share more of what you are doing, maybe we can find a better solution.

**Edit :**
After seeing your JSFiddle, here is a proposition to handle your problem using only a computed property ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L7o62g8q/)) :

```
data: {
  search: [],
  products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "first product",
      category: "first category",
      image: "first_image.jpg",
      barcode: "123123123"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "second product",
      category: "second category",
      image: "second_image.jpg",
      barcode: "23232323"
    },
  ],
  form_data: {
    category: null,
    products_credit: [],
  }
},
methods: {
    searchProducts (query) {
        //
    }
},
computed : {
  selectedProduct () {
    return this.search.map(item => {
      return {
        product_id: item.id,
        quantity: null,
        package_size: null,
        purchase_price: null,
        warehouse_id: null
      }
    })
  }
}
```

This is a preferred way to do this because the code is shorter, and there are no watchers which are resource-expensive. Also it handles removing items from the user's search at the same time.

Comment: Actually I understand your result but it returns duplicated inputs too! I don't know how!

Comment: That is very surprising. Do you think you could share your current code via http://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue or any test sharing website ?

Comment: Sorry for being late but I tried to minimize my code as I could in the JSFiddle example. Kindly check my edited answer

Comment: Here is your jsFiddle working : https://jsfiddle.net/e2cdyj1h/ , basically for your flag your were testing on `this.form_data.products_credit[x].id` instead of `this.form_data.products_credit[x].product_id` but if you are patient I might be able to work out a better solution than that :)

Comment: First (not much change) : working , without console logs and with a bit of ES6 syntaxic sugar : https://jsfiddle.net/g8uw1Lp7/

Comment: Here is a way better solution : https://jsfiddle.net/d1o3w5ah/3/ using vue computed properties. I left the watcher so you can print the array you want, but you can entirely remove it, te code will work the same. Watchers are expansive in resources, so it is best to avoid them when possible :) Also the code is shorter, and it handles removing item from the search bar too ;) (will update my answer)

Comment: man thank you! that was very helpful.. I have spend more than 3 hours in this problem

Comment: with pleasure. Answer updated with the latest solution :)